# Change views when clicking on tabs in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to have a view with a tabBar, and connect the tabs to show different views on click?

Thankx in advance!

Comment: Google much ? 'sencha touch 2 docs' and 'sencha touch 2 examples'

Answer (score 0):

Yup, there's one built into the SDK even: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel

The views you wish to switch between are just children of the tab panel view:

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: 'Home Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Yeah i knew about the actual existence of a tab panel in sencha touch 2... What i didn't know was how to link the views to the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was easier than i thought!

```
items: [
    {
         xtype: 'xtype of the view you want to link to'
    }]
```

Comment: Edited response with an example, from the doc's.